# check if page title is writes in Arabic or in English

Tags: angular, typescript

ho to check if page title is writes  in Arabic or in English in ts , to determine the direction of "..." , and put word in right or left of the tab ??

```
onCheckTitle(page) {
   if(page.title.length > 10 ){
      page.shortTitle =" ... "+page.title.substring(0,10);
   } else {
      page.shortTitle =page.title;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To check for Arabic, you could check if the text string has [Arabic Unicode Codepoints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode) in it:

```
function hasArabicCodepoints(s) {
    return /[\u0600-\u06FF]/.test(s);
}
```

Then you could set the correct CSS style property, if needed: `elem.style.direction="ltr";` or `elem.style.direction="rtl";`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way if you are the backend owner is adding lang attribute in html tag or title tag then it's easy to guess which language is used.

otherways, you can test for a string such as name of website if it's used in every page title